# Error in array on aggregation query with lookup & nest array of objects

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a problem with a query that I can't solve 100%

The fact is that when a user does not have any comment within the post. As inside the comments there is a "createdBy" and I need to make a lookup of that user inside the array. If there are no comments, it returns an array with an empty object, but it must return an empty array, not with empty objects.

Who can help me? Thank you very much in advance!

HERE MY **USER collection  (data)**

```
[
  {
    _id: ObjectId("619d0f5df3f74665aff1a551"),
    name: "Test Name",
    surname: "Test Surname2",
    createdAt: ISODate("2021-11-11T17:21:58.624+01:00"),
    updatedAt: ISODate("2021-11-25T10:35:25.842+01:00"),
    posts: [
      {
        _id: ObjectId("619d0f5df3f74575aff1a551"),
        updatedAt: ISODate("2021-11-23T16:57:17.816+01:00"),
        createdAt: ISODate("2021-11-23T16:57:17.816+01:00"),
        content: "Test content....",
        comments: [
          {
            createdBy: ObjectId("618d4326f1668007b3b98404"),
            comment: "test comment...",
            _id: ObjectId("619dfaaaa88266dc91b9489c"),
          },
          {
            createdBy: ObjectId("618d4326f1668007b3b98404"),
            comment: "test comment...",
            _id: ObjectId("619dfc60a88266dc91b95741"),
          },
        ],
        date: ISODate("2021-11-23T16:57:17.820+01:00"),
      },
      {
        _id: ObjectId("619d0f5df3f74575aff1a551"),
        updatedAt: ISODate("2021-11-23T16:57:17.816+01:00"),
        createdAt: ISODate("2021-11-23T16:57:17.816+01:00"),
        content: "Test content....",
        comments: [],
        date: ISODate("2021-11-23T16:57:17.820+01:00"),
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("619d0f5df3f74665aff1a551"),
    name: "Test Name",
    surname: "test surname",
    createdAt: ISODate("2021-11-11T17:21:58.624+01:00"),
    updatedAt: ISODate("2021-11-25T10:35:25.842+01:00"),
    posts: [
      {
        _id: ObjectId("619d0f5df3f74575aff1a551"),
        updatedAt: ISODate("2021-11-23T16:57:17.816+01:00"),
        createdAt: ISODate("2021-11-23T16:57:17.816+01:00"),
        content: "Test content....",
        comments: [
          {
            createdBy: ObjectId("618d4326f1668007b3b98404"),
            comment: "test comment...",
            _id: ObjectId("619dfaaaa88266dc91b9489c"),
          },
          {
            createdBy: ObjectId("618d4326f1668007b3b98404"),
            comment: "test comment...",
            _id: ObjectId("619dfe7ba88266dc91b961b6"),
          },
        ],
        date: ISODate("2021-11-23T16:57:17.820+01:00"),
      },
      {
        _id: ObjectId("619d0f5df3f74575aff1a551"),
        updatedAt: ISODate("2021-11-23T16:57:17.816+01:00"),
        createdAt: ISODate("2021-11-23T16:57:17.816+01:00"),
        content: "Test content....",
        comments: [
          {
            createdBy: ObjectId("618d4326f1668007b3b98404"),
            comment: "test comment...",
            _id: ObjectId("619dfaaaa88266dc91b9489c"),
          },
          {
            createdBy: ObjectId("618d4326f1668007b3b98404"),
            comment: "test comment...",
            _id: ObjectId("619dfc60a88266dc91b95741"),
          },
        ],
        date: ISODate("2021-11-23T16:57:17.820+01:00"),
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

HERE MY **AGGREGATE QUERY**

```
db.users.aggregate([
    { $unwind: { path: '$posts', preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true } },
    { $unwind: { path: '$posts.comments', preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true } },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: 'users',
            localField: 'posts.comments.createdBy',
            foreignField: '_id',
            as: 'posts.comments.createdBy'
        }
    },
    { $unwind: { path: '$posts.comments.createdBy', preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true } },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: { _id: '$_id', post_id: '$posts._id' },
            name: { $first: '$name' },
            posts: { $push: '$posts' },
            comments: { $push: '$posts.comments' },
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: '$_id._id',
            name: { $first: '$name' },
            posts: {
                $push: {
                    _id: '$_id.post_id',
                    date: { $first: '$posts.date' },
                    content: { $first: '$posts.content' },
                    comments: '$comments'
                }
            }
        }
    },
])
```

Here an image with the fail array:

[image]

Comment: Please tell what output you want & please provide user data ?

Comment: all of this is included in my question

Answer (score 0):

you have to  remove preserveNullAndEmptyArrays field from unwind to don't have empity objects

Comment: If I remove the preserveNullAndEmptyArrays the posts that don't have comments also disappear, but I need them

Comment: ok createdBy and _id of the users are ObjectId or 1 of this is a string?

Comment: because seem that not find any user that comment the post

Comment: Hi Marco, thanks! It is a ObjectId not string

Comment: np have a nice day and leave and up :)

Comment: createdBy is ObjectId. but it still doesn't work correctly :( 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHpig.png

Comment: the field you match is an ObjectID?

Comment: Yes, that's why it is strange, and I think that when doing the push for some reason it adds an empty object to the array {}